# Cannot include mysql.h

Tags: c, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use MySQL API in my C program. The problem: it seems that mysql.h library does not exists, but if I don't go wrong it shoud be available if I install MySQL Connector (I have installed it via the **MySQL Installer - Community**, its path is C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0).

I have another question: is that valid even for a C program? Or should I install the C one?

Comment: `mysql.h` is a *header* file. If it is not being found, it is because it is not in the default *header_search_path*. You specify the additional path to search with `-I/path/to/where/it/is` included in your compile string. (or you can set the appropriate compiler option if using the VS Code IDE). If I was using mysql connector in a C project, then I would install the C version of the connector instead of the C++ version. Especially if using MinGW gcc instead of g++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Have you ever specified an addtional path in Microsoft Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Yes, you simply add the search path as specified in [VC++ Directories Property Page - MSDN - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx)